# how to fill webGrid through dropdown selection in mvc 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

Hi; i want to fill webGrid after selection dropdownlist. But i can not. i've been selected drb1 and then filling drb2. Bu i can not fill webGrid1 after selection drb2. Also i can not fing any sample by googling.How to fill webgrid? My aim is descripted below:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to the `change` event of this second dropdown list? What part are you having problems with? Posting a sketch of the desired result is something that you should give to your programmers to implement, not to ask such question on Stack Oveflow. Don't hesitate to show us what you have tried so far (in terms of code) once you get more focused question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by call an action on selecteditem change of the dropdown

Inside the action you can use the SelectedText of the DropDown and use entity framework for calling sql

Once data is return back tranform it to your model and return it back in to the View

```
The view you will need 
@model IEnumerable<Product>
<div>
@{
  var grid = new WebGrid(Model, defaultSort:"Price");
}
@grid.GetHtml()
</div>
```

Some nice example :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx
http://weblogs.asp.net/andrebaltieri/archive/2010/11/01/asp-net-mvc-3-working-with-webgrid.aspx